# Error Message Handling For Form Elements In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, es6-promise

[image]

I have a function isValid on userInput function.
When I am trying to validate, the error messages is applied for all all form elements; instead of the invalid ones.

Can some one help on this. I can provide additional information on this.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import TextboxScannerElement from './TextboxScannerElement';

export default function CollectionContainerPage(props) {
  const [pageUserInput, setPageUserInput] = useState([]);
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.pageData !== undefined) {
      setPageUserInput([...props.pageData]);
    }
  }, [props.pageData]);

  **async function onUserInput(element, value) {
    console.log(element);
    if (typeof element === 'string') {
      let pageUserInputCopy = [...pageUserInput];
      let index = pageUserInputCopy.findIndex((obj) => obj.key === element);
      let itemCopy = { ...pageUserInputCopy[index] };
      itemCopy['userInput'] = value;
      pageUserInputCopy[index] = itemCopy;

      setPageUserInput(pageUserInputCopy);

      let valid = await isValid(value);
      if (!valid) {
        setErrorMessage("Collection Container ID already exists!");
        setHasError(true);
      }
    }

  }**
  function isCodeExists(userInput) {
    setErrorMessage('');
    setHasError(false);
    let code = encodeURIComponent(userInput);
    const testURL =
      loris.BaseURL +
      '/biosample/ajax/validateScannableCode.php' +
      '?scannable_code=' +
      code;

    return fetch(
      testURL,
      {
        credentials: 'include',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        if(responseData==2) {
          return 2;
        }
        else{
          return 1;
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.warn(error));;

  }
  async function isValid(userInput) {
    const response = await isCodeExists(userInput);
    if (response == 2) {
      return false;
    }
    else {

      return true;
    }
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
     props.updatePageData(pageUserInput);
      props.nextStep();
  }

  function previous() {
    props.updatePageData(pageUserInput);
    props.prevStep();
  }

  const form =
    pageUserInput.length === 0
      ? null
      : pageUserInput.map(({ label, key, userInput }) => (
          <TextboxScannerElement
            keyStr={key}
            label={label}
            name={key}
            onUserInput={onUserInput}
            value={userInput}
            errorMessage={errorMessage}
          />
        ));

  return (
    <>
      <div className="instructions">
        <strong>Instructions:</strong>
        <p>Scan the Collection Containers found in the kit.</p>
      </div>
      <FormElement
        className="FormElement"
        name="form"
        fileUpload={false}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        onUserInput={onUserInput}
      >
        {form}
        <ButtonElement
          label="Next"
          onUserInput={onUserInput}
          // disabled={!canSubmit}
        />
      </FormElement>
      <button
        onClick={previous}
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-primary prevButton"
      >
        Back
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a single state(errorMessage) to manage errors of all fields of the form. In this case as soon as validation of any one field fails, error msg will be set for all the fields as the same value is being used as error msg for all the fields of the form.
Instead of having a single string as a error msg you can have the format of state as below:

```
const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState({
    field1: '',
    field2: '',
    field3: ''
});

function onUserInput(element,value){
    // assuming 'element' is some key to differentiate between fields
    setPageUserInput({
      ...pageUserInput,
      [element]: value
    })
    let valid = await isValid(value);
    if (!valid) {
        setErrorMessage({
          ...errorMessage,
          [element]: "Collection Container ID already exists!"}
         );
       // setHasError(true);   -> it is not needed as you can have check if error msg is empty or not
      }
  }
```

If you are receiving data from API, you can simply pass the value of a particular key from data to the prop of input fields.

```
const CustomInput =()=>{
  const [inputVal,setInputVal] = useState({
    field1: '',
    field2: ''
  });

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('apiURL').then((res)=>{
      setInputVal({
        field1: res.field1,
        field2: res.field2
      })
    })
  },[])
  
  const onUserInput=()=>{
    // on change code here
  }
  return(){
    <div>
      <input value={inputVal["field1"]} onChange={(e)=> onUserInput("field1",e)} />
      {errorMessage["field1"] ? errorMessage["field1"] : <></>}
      <input value={inputVal["field2"]} onChange={(e)=> onUserInput("field2",e)} />
      {errorMessage["field2"] ? errorMessage["field2"] : <></>}
    </div> 
  }
}
```

Hope I resolved your doubt. If not, do comment so that I can explain better.

Comment: Thank you so much; May be I am asking too much; But how can I set the element name/field as it is arbitrary data coming from database.

Comment: Updated answer for you. :)

Comment: Can you make it compatible with the above code. The fetch data is in props.pageData

Comment: Can you explain a little better